# R apply function over arrays

Tags: arrays, r, apply

I have an issue with the command apply and I don't understand why my solution doesn't work.

Let's say I have this matrix called $A$ with dimensions $m\times n$. I would like to apply a function to every element of it, so I use B<-apply(A,c(1,2),function). That works and I have my results in another matrix with dimensions $m\times n$.

No I would like to arrange these results in an array $C$ of dimensions $m \times n \times k$.

If I write something like C[,,1]<-apply(A,c(1,2),function) or even C[,,1]<-B it doesn't work and I end up with dim(C)=NULL.

I don't really know what's happening here, if it's needed I'll post the specific code I'm using, though I think the problem may be related with apply.

EDIT: Code

```
LTV<-pxt_CBD_male
LTV[,,]<-0
LTV=LTV[,,1:6]
dimnames(LTV)[[3]]<-c("0.00","-0.02","-0.04","-0.06","-0.08","-0.10")
> dim(LTV)
[1] 36 50  6
> class(LTV)
[1] "array"


p=0.05
etalim=qnorm(1-p,mean=ext_mean_male[,],sd=ext_sd_male[,])
> dim(etalim)
[1] 36 50
> class(etalim)
[1] "matrix"

r<-0.015
c<--(0.00)
l1<-0.025
l2<-0.005
nstep<-100
H<-c()
H[1]=100
z<-c(seq(0,nstep))
y<-z[z!=nstep]
for(t in 1:nstep){
  H[t+1]=H[t]*(1+c)
}

LTVfunction<-function(x){
  y1=H[trunc(x)]
  y2=H[trunc(x)+1]
  x1=trunc(x)
  x2=trunc(x)+1
  y=((x-x1)/(x2-x1))*(y2-y1)+y1
  value=y/(1+r+l1)^x
  return(value)
}
```

Now the problem arises. The first works, the second doesn't:

```
LTV1<-apply(etalim,c(1,2),LTVfunction)
> dim(LTV1)
[1] 36 50
> class(LTV1)
[1] "matrix"
LTV[,,1]<-apply(etalim,c(1,2),LTVfunction)
> dim(LTV)
NULL
> class(LTV)
[1] "list"
```

Comment: "if it's needed I'll post the specific code I'm using", yes please. That is how you ask good questions and get fast answers

Comment: Done, thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

I would pre-allocate the array and then assign to it:

```
tmp <- matrix(rnorm(100), 10, 10)

out <- array(0, dim = c(dim(tmp), 3))

out[,,1] <- apply(tmp, c(1, 2), function(x) x + 1)
out[,,2] <- apply(tmp, c(1, 2), function(x) x - 1)
```

Comment: In your example I wouldn't use a loop at all.

Comment: when the OP doesn't furnish an example when first posting, I don't spend much time coming up with a realistic answer. I wouldn't use a loop for something inherently vectorised, either